# Codeigniter UNION query issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having problem with UNION query in codeigniter. Its giving output but the name is same for both columns in array.

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM user_profile WHERE user_id ='".$id."'

 UNION SELECT email FROM user WHERE id='".$id."'";

$data = $this->db->query($sql);

print_r($data->result());
```

and this is the output:

```
  Array
(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => Dimpy
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => sigsnusp@gmail.com
        )

)
```

Comment: Please learn to use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Teresko, he uses codeigniter. And it wouldn't be practical to begin to implent your own MySQL drivers into it.
However Dimple, you should be sure the data you use is not parsed by the browser.

Comment: when you need to seperate columns use joins instead of union

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.firstname,t2.email FROM user_profile as t1 join user as t2 on t1.id = t2.id where WHERE t2.id='".$id."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet [UNION query in Code Igniter](http://wiki.mantraalchemy.com/php/union-query-in-code-igniter/)

IF still have problem then there is an other alternative sub query library for codeingiter
on github [CodeIgniter-Subqueries](https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries)

I hope it will work for you!